# Error Laravel "NO MESSAGE"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

estoy creando un sistema de login con laravel pero al parecer tengo un error y no logro detectar cual es, resulta que inicia sesion con exito pero al querer cerrar la session mi botton no funciona y ademas al verificar la ruta "logout" manualmente introduciendola en el navegador me arroja el mensaje ""No Message"

a continuacion el codigo de la vista inicio (que contiene el boton de logout)

```
<li><form method="POST" action="{{ route('logout') }}"> {{ csrf_field() }} <button action="{{ route('logout') }}" class="btn btn-danger" title="Sign Out"><i class="zmdi zmdi-power"></i></button></form></li>
```

el codigo de mi controlador llamado loginController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        return view('auth.login');
    }


    public function login()
    {
       $credentials = $this->validate(request(), [
        'email' => 'email|required|string',
        'password' => 'required|string'
        ]);

       if(Auth::attempt($credentials))
       {

        return redirect()->route('inicio');

       }

       return back()
       ->withErrors(['email' => trans('auth.failed')])
       ->withInput(request(['email']));
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        Auth::logout();

        return redirect('/');
    }

}
```

y por ultimo mi archivo de rutas:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->middleware('guest');

Route::get('inicio', 'InicioController@index')->name('inicio');



Route::post('login', 'Auth\LoginController@login')->name('login');
Route::post('logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

Espero puedan ayudarme que me esta quebrando la cabezaaa!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo probaría a cambiar el `<li>` que tienes para el botón y separaría la etiqueta de ancla `<a>` de la de `<form>`. Un ejemplo:

```
<a href="{{ route('logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('frm-logout').submit();">
    Logout
</a>    
<form id="frm-logout" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

Un saludo

Comment: Muchas gracias! resolviste mi problema!

Answer (score 1):

El problema con tu método es que es confuso con un botón dentro de un formulario que además tiene un action. Es posible que los navegadores estén tomando el camino incorrecto.

Lo que recomienda Laravel es usar un botón o enlace fuera del formulario:

```
<a onclick="event.preventDefault();document.getElementById('logout').submit();">
    Salir
</a>
<form action="{{ route('auth.logout') }}" method="post" id="logout">
    {{ csrf_field() }}
</form>
```

La diferencia con la otra respuesta es que no se necesita el elemento href en el enlace, básicamente sobra.